# Cockpit, Task list, Admin are not showing in Camunda

Tags: formsflow.ai, formsflow

While I login into camunda UI as reviewer who has camunda admin permission. But Cockpit, Task list, Admin are not showing in Camunda welcome page.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Login with an admin user and check the user list and the user's permissions. The user needs to have the group "**camunda-admin**". Did you maybe spell it without a dash or so?

Alternatively you could add the explicit authorization for tasklist or cockpit. See https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.16/webapps/admin/authorization-management/

[image]